# AIC calculated in lm(y~1) and stepwise selection in R

Tags: r, model-selection, aic, bic

http://www.stat.wisc.edu/courses/st333-larget/aic.pdf

The AIC calculated with the model lm(SAT~1) was 560.4736, but the AIC calculated with stepwise selection starting with lm(SAT~1) was 419.42.  May I ask why there is a difference?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Could you copy, or at least indicate the location of, the relevant part of the PDF?

Comment: the author demonstrated how to calculate AIC on page 2 and then demonstrated forward selection on the bottom of page 3

Comment: These are two different models.  The first has only an intercept, while the second has several variables as selected by forward selection.

Comment: > step(lm(SAT~1),SAT~.,direction="forward")
Start:  AIC=419.42
SAT ~ 1


Call:
lm(formula = SAT ~ 1)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
      948.4 

The starting AIC has considered several variables?

Comment: Ah.  I misunderstood your question because I was confused about what you were looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the note in the referenced paper:

> This is what the functions AIC and BIC calculate in R. The AIC and BIC
>   formulas in your textbook ignore the leading two terms n + n log 2π
>   and use p instead of p + 1.

It looks like the "step" function in R uses the latter convention.  You'll find that the difference between the two AICs here is n + n log 2π + 2, which is a quantity that doesn't depend on the model itself, and so doesn't have any effect on model selection.